# nginx for rtsp publish load balancing

Tags: nginx, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am trying to loadbalance rtsp publish requests using nginx.I am able to redirect the publish request to RTSP server using UDP loadbalancing.But when multiple clients trying to publish ,I am facing the issue.I tried the different options of transparent,reuseport but nothing worked.

Is it possible to loadbalance rtsp pubish requests using nginx?Please find the config file

> stream {
>           upstream backend  {
>                   server 192.168.27.32:8080;
>           }
>
> ```
>     upstream rtsp_video {
>             server 192.168.27.32:5004 ;
>     }
>     upstream rtsp_audio {
>             server 192.168.27.32:5006 ;
>     }
>     server {
>             listen 5004 udp reuseport;
>             proxy_pass rtsp_video;
>             #proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port ;
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$remote_port transparent; //partially working
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$remote_port ; #working with one client
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$server_port;
>             proxy_responses 0;
>     }
>     server {
>             listen 5006 udp reuseport;
>             proxy_pass rtsp_audio;
>             #proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port ;
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$remote_port transparent; //partially working
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$remote_port ; #working with one client
>             #proxy_bind $server_addr:$server_port;
>             proxy_responses 0;
>     }
>
>     server {
>             listen 8080;
>
>             proxy_pass backend;
>             proxy_bind $server_addr;
>             #proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
>     } }
> ```